# pull using git including submodule

Tags: git, github

In  one of my iOS project I have add a sub-module added, lets say a friend of my wants to pull it including the submodule, how can he do this? Whenever I tried to download the zip file from github it doesn't pull the submodule along with it

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can clone with the `--recursive` option in order to automatically initialize and update the submodules (and any submodules that those submodules contain, etc.)

```
git clone --recursive <URL-OF-REPOSITORY>
```

Answer (score 94):

That's by design.  Get the submodules as a second step.

```
git clone git://url...
cd repo
git submodule update --init
```

Then afterwards, add another step after the `git pull`.

```
git pull ...
git submodule update --recursive
```

Of course, this only works if the submodules are set up correctly in the first place...

Comment: Extremely useful answer: I find myself forgetting `--recursive` from `git clone` all the time.

Comment: git submodule update --recursive doesn't do anything for me at all.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Late reply, but you need to do `git submodule update --recursive --init`. The init option downloads the submodule itself.