# fatal error: 'jssy.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, macos, compiler-errors

On macOS:

I tried to compile `libipatcher` with

```
./autogen.sh
```

Then I get this error:

> libipatcher.cpp:17:10: fatal error: 'jssy.h' file not found #include "jssy.h"
>                ^~~~~~~~
>       1 error generated.
>       make[1]: *** [libipatcher_la-libipatcher.lo] Error 1
>       make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1

And the developer has a `jssy` Xcode project where the `jssy.h` file is located.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you forget to run `./configure`?

Comment: no i run ./configure but i still have this problem the program does not find the jssy.h file

Comment: What parameters are you passing to `./configure`?

Comment: i used no paramether only ./configure and afterwards i used make install

Comment: Don't you need to pass the location of jssy to ./configure?  How else will it know where to find it?

Comment: Which paramater I have to use to add jssy.h?

Comment: On further inspection, these are all in `libipatcher/external/` already.  Did you fetch the git remotes?

Comment: Sorry I come from germany, so what do you mean with remote?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote

Comment: Oh no i don‘t fetch the git remotes, how can i fetch them?

Comment: [jssy is in a submodule](https://github.com/tihmstar/libipatcher/tree/master/external). So use [`git clone --recursive`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090761/pull-using-git-including-submodule)

Answer (score 2):

[jssy is in a submodule](https://github.com/tihmstar/libipatcher/tree/master/external) so you need to fetch it.

To do so, according to [pull using git including submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090761/pull-using-git-including-submodule), either:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/tihmstar/libipatcher.git
```

or:

```
git submodule init; git submodule update
```

or use SourceTree.

Then you can attempt `./autogen.sh`.

Comment: thanks, so the jssy.h problem is solved, but now it says

Comment: libipatcher.cpp:18:10: fatal error: 'xpwn/libxpwn.h' file not found
#include <xpwn/libxpwn.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [libipatcher_la-libipatcher.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2